# JSON Maximum length problem with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-2.0, javascriptserializer

I am creating a asp.net 2.0 webservice which give json as output and there's a very large, can't be break down, dataset which exceed the max length limit

I have search on the internet, and there's solution on .net 3.5 & 4, but not 2.0.

Can any tell me how can I increase the JSON legth limit?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this same exact problem.  Was getting frustrated seeing 3.5 and 4.0 solutions.  Turns out you do the same thing, you just have to add a couple lines to the `<ConfigSections>` tag in your Web.config.  It should be the first element under the root when you paste it in.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

and then add in the actual `<system.web.extensions>` section:

```
<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
    <webServices>
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
    </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```