# Increase json response maxJsonLength in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I am getting following error in razor view engine MVC4(.net 4.5) application when loading a large JSON response form server at

“**Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer.The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property at  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(jsondata**)”

I have tried by setting MaxJsonLength property in my web.config:

```
configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Tried following at server side while sending JSON response as well.

```
 return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = data,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
        JsonRequestBehavior = behavior,
        MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
    };
```

Also tried the solution listed hare: http://brianreiter.org/2011/01/03/custom-jsonresult-class-for-asp-net-mvc-to-avoid-maxjsonlength-exceeded-exception/. But nothing worked for me :(

Can some suggest me how to avoid this error or how to increase the Jason response max length?

Comment: Have you tried the solution suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860053/json-maximum-length-problem-with-asp-net ?

Comment: Yes I have also tired this solution. But no sucess

Comment: `I have also tired this solution` Nice Freudian slip :-)

Answer (score 24):

Somehow I get rid of this error by using following code in view.

```
@{
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
}
<script type="text/javascript">
var entries = @Html.Raw(serializer.Serialize(Model.FeedEntries));    
</script>
```

This was not working at server side at least for me.

Comment: This helps if you must serialize the model in the View.

Answer (score 19):

My penny to the solutions. Did b) because a) gave errormessage 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult does not contain a definition for maxJsonLength ... ' in Mvc 4.5 AFAIK, this is the only workaround that works.

I put b) in my controller. Hopefully this will help someone.

Regards, SM

a)

```
var jsonResult = Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
jsonResult.maxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
return jsonResult;
```

b)

```
if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
   //Working solution
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue, RecursionLimit = 100 };

   return new ContentResult()
   {
      Content = serializer.Serialize(list),
      ContentType = "application/json",
   };

   //Trial 2
   //var jsonResult = Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   //jsonResult.maxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
   //return jsonResult;

   //Trial 1
   //return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: In MVC 4, solution a) works. Notice the uppercase 'M' in jsonResult.MaxJsonLength

Answer (score 4):

This worked to me

```
   return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data=jsonData,
                MaxJsonLength = 86753090,
                JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
```

Comment: Tried many things that did not work, and this did the trick, nice one!